# Access Private IP via Public Ip address

Tags: ubuntu

I have two IP addresses for the application and database in ubuntu OS. One is a public IP address and the other is private. How am I supposed to add a private IP address to the public so that I can access the database on it via an application on a public server.

Comment: IP has no distinction between public and private IP addresses; to IP they are just IP addresses. The private IPv4 address ranges were arbitrarily chosen, and it is only by agreement that packets with private addresses will not be forwarded on the public Internet, not enforced by IP. Inside your own company, you can have a mixture of public and private IP networks (not uncommon) and route between them with no problem.

Comment: If I have to use Private IP for DB setup how am I supposed to do?

Comment: Describe your setup in greater detail, probably including relevant database config files, and output of e.g. `ip a`

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* what you are asking is how to pass the database's port through from your public IP to your private? Such a port forwarding? Is the intent that the same port you connect to the database should be accessible from inside or outside the network same server, same port?

IN that case a port forward is likely what you are looking for, almost all routers are capable of this to some degree. IN most consumer routers they call it just that "port forwarding" and it will ask what port you want to listen on, on your WAN, and then what LAN IP/PORT you would like it to be forwarded to.

Now.. Depending on the database in question (Arguably most), this may not be the best, or worse remotely secure, design principal, as you likely just want to expose some data model, not a database for direct querying.

As others have stated, to address further would require more information on setup and intent, but as I read that question, it seemed port forwarding/PAT is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward solution would be to update your database configuration to listen on the public IP.  With PostgreSQL, for instance, you would edit /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf and set `listen_addresses` so it includes your public address.  Ensure the database requires authentication and encryption.  If applicable, update your firewall to limit access.

If you need temporary access, `ssh -L $local_port:localhost:$database_port $public_ip`, has a port forwarding feature that is useful.  You now can now access your local machine at port `$local_port` where `$database_port` is specific to your database. The default for PostgreSQL is `5432`.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify which database engine you are using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.). Also specify which operating system it's running on. The answer depends on the engine type and OS.

Most database engines allow you to configure them to "listen" on specific interfaces. In your case you can have the engine listen on the public and the private interfaces. You can either have it listen on both or on one. In your case you need it to listen on the public interface (you may also require it to listen on the private interface, depending on other internal systems that need to access it). If you are going to have the database engine listen on the public interface, I recommend you use a firewall to limit access to certain external systems only via IP whitelisting.

For PostgreSQL see this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html (see listen_addresses)
For MySQL on Linux see this: https://linuxize.com/post/mysql-remote-access/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, just create a port forwarding on the computer/router connected to the internet via public IP.

E.g

80 -> 192.168.1.1:80
443 -> 192.168.1.1:443

3306 -> 192.168.1.2:3306